# Why 160dpi is considered the baseline of the resolution?

Tags: android

In measure of resolution in Android, Photoshop, 160dpi is called mdpi that 1px is equal to 1dp.
My question is why 160 not other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This official Android page covers it.
https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities

160 is just a common medium screen density. But not the only option. It is somewhat arbitary.

*"To preserve the visible size of your UI on screens with different densities, you must design your UI using density-independent pixels (dp) as your unit of measurement. One dp is a virtual pixel unit that's roughly equal to one pixel on a medium-density screen (160dpi; the "baseline" density)"*

96 was the common standard on Windows for a long time.